# Playn and multitouch?

Tags: playn

I've made this Button class, to catch the Pointer event :

```
public class Button implements Pointer.Listener {

  public void initLayer(Image defaultImage) {
    layer = parent.createImageLayer(this.defaultImage);
    layer.addListener(this);
  }

...
```

If I touch one of the instanciated buttons, I get the onPointerStart & onPointerEnd events. But, if one of my button is already touched and I start to touch another, I don't get the onPointerStart event of the second button.

Is there a way to get these multi touch events with playn ?

Comment: What platform? Android or iOS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Pointer` service is meant to abstract over either a simple touch interaction or a mouse interaction. Thus it does not support any sort of multi-touch interactions. You will not receive notifications about any touches other than the first via the `Pointer` service.

If you want to handle multiple touches, you have to use the `Touch` service, and there is currently no way to register `Touch` listeners directly on layers. So you'll have to register a global listener and do your own hit testing, and map touch movements to the layer that was first hit by that touch, etc.

Comment: Incidentally, it is now possible to register touch listeners on layers, so at least you don't have to do that part yourself. These docs describe how to do it for Pointer events but you can do the same for Touch events now: http://playn.io/cookbook/scene-graph.html#reacting-to-a-click-on-a-layer